# Liferay Export/Import LAR: automated

Tags: liferay

is there a way to create/export a LAR from liferay server A and import this in liferay server B with a script or even a maven/hudson plugin? I'm using Liferay 6.0.5.

thanks,
Stijn

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve what you want is to make use of scheduling for remote publication. You can find this option in the manage pages portlet.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you can deploy servlets in Liferay.  I would package the war file as a "web" plugin as described in [this article on Nabble](http://sun-glassfish-web-space-server.2424202.n2.nabble.com/Accessing-Liferay-APIs-from-other-servlet-td4223104.html) in order to access the Liferay APIs.  From here you could perform whatever units of work you want, of which exporting a lar file.  Call the servlet URL with the appropriate parameters and you're g2g.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to following Liferay resources to get details of Liferay API:

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/LayoutLocalServiceUtil.html

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/staging/StagingImpl.java

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, as links may go down in the future. If you could summarize the content of those links you'd but much more likely to attract upvotes.